# Sql query to get

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table that contains list of items contained in a package

PackageId, ItemId

One package may contain more than 1 item.

I want to get a list or count of packages that contains lets say Items 1 and 2

How would I do that?

Comment: Try googling for an approach... Hint: `Group by` with a `Having` Clause

Comment: This is a very simple/common query utilizing `COUNT`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING`.

Comment: "Microsoft SQL" is not very clear - are you talking about **SQL Server** (the full, relational database system), then please add `sql-server` as your tag. Or are you talking about using SQL with Microsoft Access? Then please add `ms-access` as your tag

Answer (score 0):

One way is to group on `(packageid)` and demand that each group has both items:

```
select  packageid
from    YourTable
group by
        packageid
having  max(case when itemid = 1 then 1 end) = 1
        and max(case when itemid = 2 then 1 end) = 1
```

Another is the `intersect` operator.  Demand that the package is in both sets:

```
select  packageid
from    YourTable
where   itemid = 1
intersect
select  packageid
from    YourTable
where   itemid = 2
```

Yet another way with an `inner join`.  For each row with item 1, demand that there is another row for the same package with item 2:

```
select  distinct yt1.packageid
from    YourTable yt1
join    YourTable yt2
on      yt1.packageid = yt2.packageid
where   yt1.itemid = 1
        and yt2.itemid = 2
```